# Weblogic 12c - Is there any flag to ensure the cipher order on SSL configuration?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm actually configuring an WL12c environment for a Webapp project of my Master Degree that will be used through SSL.

For the typical configuration I just add on the JVM props the following:

```
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.Ciphersuites=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128,DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384,DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA,EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA,AES128-GCM-SHA384,AES128-GCM-SHA128,AES128-SHA128,AES128-SHA128,AES128-SHA,AES128-SHA,DES-CBC3-SHA
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.protocolVersion=TLS1
```

I'm OK with the TLS1+ configuration since I'm avoiding RC4 and CBC ciphers..

My real question is, for other products, I have a flag that ensures the cipher order, answering with "the more powerful" at first. Please check the lines with **SSLHonorCipherOrder** and **ssl_prefer_server_ciphers** :

```
# apache
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 \
EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 \
EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"

# nginx
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 \
EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 \
EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
```

Weblogic 12c have some kind of flag like that? 
The order used on weblogic.security.SSL.Ciphersuites is enough? 
I don't have any confirmation from the Oracle docs on my findings.

EDIT: I'm using Java 1.7

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No WL have flag to ensure that. No plans to implement this soon as well.

From Oracle Support:

**Reply 1:**

No, with the JSSE implementation there is no documented feature in WLS 12.1.2 of honoring the server-side SSL cipher suite preferred order.

**Reply 2:**

Thank you for you patience while I was obtaining the confirmation regarding any possible ordering of cipher suites.
Unfortunately, as of WLS 12.1.2 there is no documented feature of honoring the server-side SSL cipher suite preferred order.

This may change for future WLS versions. I'm currently trying to obtain information if this feature would be planed to be added in any future version, if this would be of your interest.

**Reply 3:**

I have received confirmation from our product management that such a option like 'SSLHonorCipherOrder' is not planned to be included in the future.

But maybe this is actually not needed by you as the following is true for WLS and I believe that is what you actually want to achieve:
During an SSL handshake, the client sends a list of cipher suites, and the server then chooses from it's own list the strongest cipher that the client also supports.

If you would be concerned about any particular weak cipher suites, you should exclude those, i.e. configure only the strong cipher suites which you want to be used.